# composer private package based on gitlab is identified as git submodule

Tags: git, composer-php, gitlab, git-submodules, satis

I made some private packages for composer on company's gitlab.
But when require my private package on other project,it is identified as a git submodule,so I can't push it to the production environment.

I follow [composer document](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) to alter my project's composer.json.
I also try the [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis),but it turn on the same result---submodule.

When I store the package on Github, It works well!

It's the gitlab's issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you not remove Composer from the question by determining how composer interacts with GitLab (will be standard Git methods like GitHub I imagine)? This would allow many more people to answer (few people know gitlab, even less in the intersection with Composer), and you might end up answering yourself.

Comment: Sorry Santilli,I have no idea about what you said since My English is not well

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.
By the way,how do you know I'm Chinese?

Comment: 因为你姓Liao(廖?),那最可能的是中国人。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer is cloning your packages with git instead of downloading them. When composer downloads a package from github via packagist, it downloads an archive of the file (`.tar.gz`), then uncompresses it into your vendor directory. When it gets your private repository, it can't find an archive, so it clones it directly with git. This clone will have a `.git` directory, just like a normal cloned repository.

The typical solution is to add the `vendor/` directory to your `.gitignore`. However, if you have special circumstances, you can get around this by creating your own [archives with satis](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#downloads).

From the satis docs:

```
{
    "archive": {
        "directory": "dist",
        "format": "tar",
        "prefix-url": "https://amazing.cdn.example.org",
        "skip-dev": true
    }
}
```

If you do this, your packages will be archived before they are installed in the `vendor` directory. There will be no `.git` directory, so it won't be treated as a submodule.

Comment: Thanks justinhoward for solve my problem.
I get the reason:composer can only use github and bitbucket's api to download the zip archive.While in gitlab,it just git clone.
Thanks again!

Comment: @Liao I'm glad the answer was helpful! You can indicate that it solved your problem by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. This will indicate to future readers that it is a good solution.